# Particles evading cursor and other particles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a simple vanilla JS program where `x` amount of particles/objects are generated on screen and they need to evade each other and the mouse. For the overall evading I used https://gist.github.com/christopher4lis/f9ccb589ee8ecf751481f05a8e59b1dc and it worked just fine for the particles to avoid each other, but now I'm stuck on implementing the mouse evade functionality.

Everything I've tried has ended up with either particles overlapping with each other or some other bugs.

Does anyone have any tips on how to deal with this situation, or perhapse even a code snippet from previous project?

```
import {c, canvas, mouse, people} from "./canvas.js";
import {distance} from "./utils.js";

// @ts-ignore
import {resolveCollision} from './util-elastic-collision.js';

export default class Person {
    private velocity: { x: number, y: number };
    private mass: number;
    constructor(
        private _x: number,
        private _y: number,
        private radius: number,
    ) {
        this.velocity = {
            x: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2,
            y: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2,
        }
        this.mass = 1;
    }

get x() {
    return this._x;
}

set x(x: number) {
    this._x = x;
}

get y() {
    return this._y;
}

set y(y: number) {
    this._y = y;
}

draw() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this._x, this._y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.fill();
}

update() {
    this.draw();
    this.keepDistance();

    // Bounce off the mouse // Failed
    for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        let dist = distance(mouse.x, mouse.y, people[i].x, people[i].y) - 6 * this.radius;
        if (dist <= 0) {

            people[i].x += (mouse.x > people[i].x + this.radius) ? -1 : 1;
            people[i].y += (mouse.y > people[i].y + this.radius) ? -1 : 1;

        }
    }


    // Bounce off the walls
    if (this._x - this.radius < 0 || this._x + this.radius > canvas.width) {
        this.velocity.x *= -1;
    }

    if (this._y - this.radius < 0 || this._y + this.radius > canvas.height) {
        this.velocity.y *= -1;
    }

    this._x += this.velocity.x;
    this._y += this.velocity.y;
}

keepDistance() {
    // Bounce off other people
    for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if (people[i] === this) continue;
        let dist = distance(this._x, this._y, people[i].x, people[i].y) - 4 * this.radius;
        if (dist <= 0) {
            resolveCollision(this, people[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Assuming that the calculation for distance are correct and taking your work everything is OK on the `keepDistance` why not use the same `resolveCollision` on the mouse ... is hard to reproduce with the sample you provided, do you have the rest somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would change:
`dist = distance(this._x, this._y, people[i].x, people[i].y) - 4 * this.radius;`

to the following:
`dist = distance(this._x, this._y, people[i].x, people[i].y) - (this.radius + people[i].radius);`

That should give you realistic collisions when your circles are different radius

---

Then on the mouse object collision, I would start with something like:

```
    var dist = distance(mouse.x, mouse.y, people[i].x, people[i].y) - people[i].radius;
    if (dist <= 100) {
        let m = new Person(mouse.x, mouse.y, 100);
        //TODO set proper velocity
        m.velocity = { x: 2, y: 2 };
        resolveCollision(m, people[i]);
    }
```

This way we reuse the resolveCollision keeping the same effect as the collision between the other objects. You do need to find a way to set a proper velocity for the mouse as-is it assumes the mouse is moving right and down.

Something else I noticed once we introduce the mouse `resolveCollision` just swaps the velocities:
https://github.com/AlverPalk/collision/blob/master/src/ts/util-elastic-collision.js#L58
I think it should also introduce a reduction of the velocities at collision, as energy loss at impact, if not every collision with the mouse will increase velocity to the point the entire system will be moving really fast

---

code is on my fork:
https://github.com/heldersepu/collision/commits/master